# Renaming part of a filename

Tags: bash, filenames, rename

I have loads of files which look like this:

```
DET01-ABC-5_50-001.dat
...
DET01-ABC-5_50-0025.dat
```

and I want them to look like this:

```
DET01-XYZ-5_50-001.dat
...
DET01-XYZ-5_50-0025.dat
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

There are a couple of variants of a rename command, in your case, it may be as simple as

```
rename ABC XYZ *.dat
```

You may have a version which takes a Perl regex;

```
rename 's/ABC/XYZ/' *.dat
```

Comment: I don't rename is available in all Unix variants. Sed is a good fall back.

Comment: Not working for me, nothing happens

Comment: I had to use `'s/ABC*/XYZ/'` as regex for files like `ABCD...`

Comment: You suggestions didn't work for me, but this command worked: `$ find . -name '*ABC*' -exec rename 's/ABC/XYZ/' {} \;` I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: There is `perl-rename` for some distros which work with your second example.

Comment: On  CentOS Linux 7, I used it as 'rename 'ABC'  'XYZ'  *.dat`

Comment: @user3405291 - this command works better for large number of files, when the original answer fails due to too many arguments of asterisk expansion

Comment: That was too easy. Awesome. :)
For anyone on windows PowerTools has PowerRename that has a lot of options and works really well.

Answer (score 172):

```
for file in *.dat ; do mv $file ${file//ABC/XYZ} ; done
```

No `rename` or `sed` needed. Just bash [parameter expansion](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-parameter-expansion).

Comment: If file names are having space, you should use quote. See snippet below...
`for file in *.dat ; do mv "$file" "${file//ABC/XYZ}" ; done`

Comment: Works great on OSX

Answer (score 9):

Something like this will do it. The `for` loop may need to be modified depending on which filenames you wish to capture.

```
for fspec1 in DET01-ABC-5_50-*.dat ; do
    fspec2=$(echo ${fspec1} | sed 's/-ABC-/-XYZ-/')
    mv ${fspec1} ${fspec2}
done
```

You should always test these scripts on *copies* of your data, by the way, and in totally different directories.

Comment: for osx this the stuff. rename looks cool, but a brew install of rename seems to install a perl script which didn't work per the example above. Some googling indicated that rename isn't available on all linux vars and that there is infact a perl version floating about.  I got about 10 minutes into trying to sort out the differences and decides - you know this answer is just easy enough :).

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to learn how to use sed http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed

And also to use for so you can loop through your file entries http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Your command will look something like this, I don't have a term beside me so I can't check

```
for i in `dir` do mv $i `echo $i | sed '/orig/new/g'`
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to do this with sed. In you case:

```
for x in DET01-*.dat; do
    echo $x | sed -r 's/DET01-ABC-(.+)\.dat/mv -v "\0" "DET01-XYZ-\1.dat"/'
done | sh -e
```

It is best to omit the "sh -e" part first to see what will be executed.

Comment: maybe I am doing something wrong, but this is doing nothing to my files?

Comment: Are you trying with or without the "sh -e"? If you are trying without it is not supposed to. It just prints what will be executed ("mv -v ... ..." lines) as a chance to check if everything is ok. If you like what you see add the "sh -e".

Comment: and renaming only a part, i.e the extension? I've to rename a lot of .TTF files as .ttf...

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers are simple and good. However, I always like to add an interactive mode to these scripts so that I can find false positives.

```
if [[ -n $inInteractiveMode ]]
then
    echo -e -n "$oldFileName => $newFileName\nDo you want to do this change? [Y/n]: "
    read run

    [[ -z $run || "$run" == "y" || "$run" == "Y" ]] && mv "$oldFileName" "$newFileName"
fi
```

Or make interactive mode the default and add a force flag (-f | --force) for automated scripts or if you're feeling daring. And this doesn't slow you down too much: the default response is "yes, I do want to rename" so you can just hit the enter key at each prompt (because of the `-z $run` test.