# change part of file name grep or rename

Tags: grep, rename, file-rename

I have various files that are names

> `"type_featAtype_featB"`

and

> "type_featAtype_featC"

I need that all

> "type_featA"

are replaced with

> "START"

so the new names of the folders would be called

> "STARTtype_featB"

and

> STARTtype_featC"

.

I have been looking at the rename function [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/150) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392768/rename-part-of-filename)

However, not all of my files have the same suffix, in fact they all have different suffixes as indicated in the example.

Thus, I am looking for insight on how to use a command to replace just a part of the file name, as indicated above in one folder where each file had a unique suffix.
Thank you

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: How does replacing `type_featA` with `START` transform `type_featAtype_featB` into `STARTtypeDM_featB`?

Comment: Human error: See edited question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have the `rename` utility that is a part of perl distribution, you could say:

```
rename 's/^type_featA/START/' *
```

to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 11):

A more cryptic option would be to use SED - I suppose that you would choose to do this if you had no access to the perl rename function (which I admit is more concise, and more clear):

`ls * | sed -e 'p;s/^type_featA/START/' | xargs -n2 mv`

Comment: I like this cryptic version ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The [devnull's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19544445/938111) is correct. You can even write:

```
rename 's/^type_featA/START/' my_folder/type_featA*
```

This [rename](/questions/tagged/rename) command line is perfect on Debian and other derived distributions.

But, other distributions may use a different [rename](/questions/tagged/rename) tool as for Fedora, RedHat and CentOS. In this second case the right command line is:

```
rename type_featA START my_folder/type_featA*
```

This second [rename](/questions/tagged/rename) tool will replace only the first `type_featA` occurrence.